# Why is the size of a list less than the size of the objects that comprise it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question about space in the memory used by `list` and `dict` objects.
My Python 3.7 shell shows:

```
>>> import sys
>>> list_ = []
>>> sys.getsizeof(list_)
64
>>> dict_ = {}
>>> sys.getsizeof(dict_)
240
>>> list_ += dict_,
>>> list_
[{}]
>>> sys.getsizeof(list_)
96
```

I don't understand what is going on.

- The `list` object takes `64` bytes of memory (what's shown in shell) `+ 8` bytes for each element.
- The `dict` object takes `240` bytes of memory.
- So, after adding the dictionary as an element, the `list` should take `64 + 8 + 240 = 312` bytes.

Why did the memory taken by the list increase by only `32` bytes?  What happened to the `dict`'s `240` bytes memory? And why did the amount of memory used increase by just `32` bytes?

Comment: The list holds a reference to the dictionary, not the contents of the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Kaya3 the size of the list does not include the size of the things it references.

```
>>> list_ = [{}]
>>> sys.getsizeof(list_)
40
>>> sys.getsizeof(list_[0])
136
```

Comment: Thank You kpie and @kaya3. Now i understand. But one more question. Is there any quick way to check all memory used by the list and objects referenced by the list?

Comment: Well you could write a little recursive function that digs down into the list but there could be an issue if you have a reference to the list in the list or duplicates of the same reference.

Comment: You could examine the total memory used by your process before and after instantiating the list. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938733/total-memory-used-by-python-process

Comment: thx for your help

Comment: @Marco did you [check the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof)? There is a link to a [recipe](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577504/) for just this.