# Is there a way to see how much memory does a python module take?

Tags: python-3.x, memory

In [python3](https://www.python.org) is there a **simple** way to see how much memory is used when loading a module? (**not** while running its content such as functions or methods, which may load data and so on).

```
# Memory used before, in bytes
import mymodule
# Memory used after, in bytes
# Delta memory = memory used before - memory used after
```

(E.g. these 3 comment lines of extra code to insert would be what I call "simple").

By using the [spyder](https://www.spyder-ide.org/) IDE for example, I can see in the "File explorer" tab on the top right, the size of the file (i.e. size on disk) which contains my module, but I think it's not the size that is taken into memory after Python has actually loaded its contents, with the many imports I need in there.

And in the "Memory and Swap History" part of the "System Monitor" (Ubuntu 18.04) I can see a little bump while effectively loading my module in python (it may get bigger as the module grows of course) and which is probably the amount I'm searching for:

[image: Memory usage]

My uses would mainly be inside the Spyder IDE, any [jupyter-notebook](https://jupyter.org/) or directly into a python console.

Answer (score 0):

Probably after 3 years its not relevant anymore, but I would link you to this question: [Total memory used by Python process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938733/total-memory-used-by-python-process)

Since you mention you were using Ubuntu 18.04, you can do this with the standard library module [resource](https://docs.python.org/library/resource.html)

```
resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss # peak memory usage (platform dependent)
```

Your code would look like this:

```
import resource
m1 = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
import mymodule
m2 = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
delta = m2-m1
```

I tested it with Python console, not sure if jupyter spawns another process. Also note the discussion in the linked question that the returned value is platform dependent.