# How to get RAM Usage percentage in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, psutil

Now I know there's `psutil` module for the use:

```
import psutil
a=psutil.virtual_memory()
print(a)
```

And it shows this output:

> svmem(total=4238442496, available=1836089344, percent=56.7, used=2402353152, free=1836089344)

It has got percentage, but I only want percentage of RAM usage without all other features like used, free, etc. Is it possible ? Please sort this out. Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: `a.percent`? You have an object and you want to access one part of it

Comment: I think this thread is useful for you "
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938733/total-memory-used-by-python-process>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a minor change:

```
import psutil

a = psutil.virtual_memory()
print(a.percent) # Here's a change
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Do you know ho I can do get the ram usage percent of a specific variable ?