# How can I find the total memory uses by a python program?

Tags: python, ubuntu, memory, execution, execution-time

I am running a python program in ubuntu system. I want to find out the memory size that is required to run my python program. I have use psutil but its give the snapshot of a particular time.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938733/total-memory-used-by-python-process) an answer to your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Total memory used by Python process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938733/total-memory-used-by-python-process)