# How to measure function speed, memory usage, etc in Python

Tags: python, function

In order to optimize a program, I want a simple function to show me the exact (or aprox.) speed and memory needed by a function:

```
measuring("start")
fu()
measuring("stop")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/how-to-measure-elapsed-time-in-python

Comment: You require some scales to measure speed/ space. May you mention those measures? You might be thinking about complexity, thus may you provide function and inputs?

Comment: miliseconds, seconds, megaBytes, Bytes,

Comment: Check this out [Total memory used by Python process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938733/total-memory-used-by-python-process) for memory usage.

Answer (score 3):

You can use datetime to calculate speed:

```
from datetime import datetime

startTime = datetime.now()

print(datetime.now() - startTime)
```

Output: `0:00:00.000007`

Just wrap that around your function to time it :).

Comment: How does this address the entire question? There's nothing here about memory usage.

Comment: It doesn't, I was only answering the speed part. Why don't you answer that instead of asking me why I didn't?