# Is it possible to check the memory and ram occupied by the virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, pipenv, virtual-environment

Hi recently iam working in a project. In that project i want to create a virtual environment using python and i have to monitor it (how much ram and memories occupied by the virtual environment). Is there any way to calculate it or is there any Python package to monitor the virtual environment.

Comment: I'm sure you can find the answer by searching. Just for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938733/total-memory-used-by-python-process

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Total memory used by Python process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938733/total-memory-used-by-python-process)