# Is there a way to manually kill a cloud run container through script, http request, etc.?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, out-of-memory, google-cloud-run, graceful-shutdown

I have container, which i want to kill if the memory utilisation exceeds some value. I don't the want the container to be crashed, hence, any graceful way of doing this? If there is pythonic way that would be even great.

Comment: Have a look at this question `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938733/total-memory-used-by-python-process`

Comment: I dont want memory limiter; i want to kill a gcp cloudrun container from script

Comment: It would be useful if google would let us send a SIGTERM or SIGKILL to cloud run containers. One can hope.