# How to log Python code memory consumption?

Tags: python, docker, memory

#### Question

Hi, I am runnin' a **Docker** container with a **Python** application inside. The code performs some computing tasks and I would like to monitor it's memory consumption using logs (*so I can see how different parts of the calculations perform*). I do not need any charts or continous monitoring - I am okay with the inaccuracy of this approach.

**How should I do it** without loosing performance?

Using external (AWS) tools to monitor used memory is not suitable, because I often debug using logs and thus it's very difficult to match logs with performance charts. Also the resolution is too small.

#### Setup

- using `python:3.10` as base docker image
- using `Python 3.10`
- running in AWS ECS Fargate (but results are similar while testing on local)
- running the calculation method using `asyncio`

I have read some articles about `tracemalloc`, but it says it degrades the performance a lot (around `30 %`). [The article](https://medium.com/survata-engineering-blog/monitoring-memory-usage-of-a-running-python-program-49f027e3d1ba).

#### Tried methods

I have tried the following method, however it shows the same memory usage every time called. So I doubt it works the desired way.

Using `resource`

```py
import asyncio
import resource
# Local imports
from utils import logger


def get_usage():
    usage = round(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss / 1000 / 1000, 4)
    logger.info(f"Current memory usage is: {usage} MB")

    return usage


# Do calculation - EXAMPLE
asyncio.run(
  some_method_to_do_calculations()
)
```

Logs from Cloudwatch
[image: memory-usage-in-time]

Using `psutil` (in testing)

```py
import psutil
# Local imports
from utils import logger


def get_usage():
    total = round(psutil.virtual_memory().total / 1000 / 1000, 4)
    used = round(psutil.virtual_memory().used / 1000 / 1000, 4)
    pct = round(used / total * 100, 1)
    logger.info(f"Current memory usage is: {used} / {total} MB ({pct} %)")

    return True
```

Comment: Can you use [psutil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21632554/2280890)?

Comment: [`pmap`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pmap) ?

Comment: tbh, I have discovered `psutil` few minutes after posting this question and it seems like it should fit my needs

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a memory profiler. See eg. https://pythonspeed.com/fil/

Comment: Thx, I will check `sciagraph`, looks good...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fargate is using cgroup for memory limiting.

As mentioned [here](https://fabiokung.com/2014/03/13/memory-inside-linux-containers/) and [here](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/1011), the CPU/memory values provided by `/proc` *refer to the host, not the container*.

As a result, userspace tools such as `top` and `free` report misleading values.

You can try with something like:

```
with open('/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.stat', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'hierarchical_memory_limit ' in line:
            memory_limit = int(line.split()[1])
        if 'total_rss ' in line:
            memory_usage = int(line.split()[1])                     

percentage=memory_usage*100/memory_limit
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like using `psutil` fits my needs pretty good. Thanks to all commenters!

Example

```py
import psutil
# Local imports
from utils import logger


def get_usage():
    total = round(psutil.virtual_memory().total / 1000 / 1000, 4)
    used = round(psutil.virtual_memory().used / 1000 / 1000, 4)
    pct = round(used / total * 100, 1)
    logger.info(f"Current memory usage is: {used} / {total} MB ({pct} %)")

    return True
```

Comment: Be careful: psutil inside a linux container returns wrong memory information! https://fabiokung.com/2014/03/13/memory-inside-linux-containers/ 
and 
https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/1011