# Why is querying a pandas DataFrame slower after a SQL join operation?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a pandas DataFrame that is created from a SQL query involving a join operation on three tables using `pd.read_sql()`. The DataFrame has about 1 million rows. When I try to query rows based on the value of one column (`doi`), it takes about 0.1 to 0.2 seconds for each query.

Interestingly, if I export the DataFrame to a CSV file and then load it back into memory, the same query operation is 5 to 10 times faster.

More interestingly, if I only query the main table (the resulting DataFrame has the same number of rows and two short string columns less), the resulting DataFrame is as fast as the CSV one. **Even keeping only one column (`doi`) in the DataFrame obtained from the join operation doesn't improve the performance, and it's still slower than the single-table DataFrame with the same number of rows and more columns.**

Could you help me understand this phenomenon and show me how to solve the performance issue without exporting to CSV?

**Some clarifications:**

I am referring to the difference in the query performance of DataFrames generated by SQL query with/without table joins, not the performance of joining DataFrames.

My codes to read data from the SQL Server database and query the resulting DataFrame:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}', server='XXX', database='XXX', uid='XXX', trusted_connection='yes')

query_string = """
    SELECT 
        t1.*,
        t2.short_string_column1,
        t3.short_string_column2
    FROM 
        t1
    LEFT JOIN 
        t2
    ON 
        t1.doi = t2.doi
    LEFT JOIN 
        t3
    ON 
        t1.doi = t3.doi
    """
# ~1M rows
df = pd.read_sql(query_string, conn)

# ~20K dois
doi_list = {some interested dois to query}

# this is very slow
for doi in doi_list:
    # I achieved satisfying performance on the single-table DataFrame 
    # but I needed more fields to do my work, so I have to join tables.
    required_intermediate_results = df[df.doi.values == doi]
    ......

# this is 5 to 10 times faster
df.to_csv('df.csv', index=False)
df2 = pd.read_csv('df.csv')

for doi in doi_list:
    # I achieved satisfying performance on the single-table DataFrame 
    # but I needed more fields to do my work, so I have to join tables.
    required_intermediate_results = df2[df2.doi.values == doi]
    ......
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253668/discussion-on-question-by-tom-leung-why-is-querying-a-pandas-dataframe-slower-af); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR on the phenomenon; from the experiment below, we can see that `pd.read_sql()` needs proportionally more memory than `pd.read_csv`**, where the difference in memory usage increases in dataset size. Since the difference easily goes into the Gigabytes for datasets with >1 million rows, this difference can be large enough to affect performance of subsequent operations when using `pd.read_sql`.

Since both `DataFrames` use exactly the same amount of memory once dtype parity is assured, and given that the memory overhead from instantiating the `DB engine` will be independent from the dataset size which is loaded, **the results corroborate the hypothesis that `pd.read_sql()` is proportionally more `memory-intensive` than `pd.read_csv`.**

**Recommendation to OP:** Given the identified behaviour of `pd.read_sql()`, the probably easiest solution is to save the data as a `.csv` and load it subsequently. Maybe you can divide your program into two separate scripts, the first part loading and storing the data and the second part performing the querying.

**Approach:**

I used the SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21632554/8718701) to figure out how much memory Python uses, running the following two pieces of code in a jupyter notebook.

```
import os
import psutil
import sys

import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dbname="postgres"
user="postgres"
password="root"
host="localhost"
port="5432"

connection_string = f"dbname={dbname} user={user} password={password} host={host} port={port}"
conn = psycopg2.connect(connection_string)

df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM staging_spread", con=conn)

process = psutil.Process()
print(df.shape)  # (195976, 6)
print(process.memory_info().rss/(1024*1024))  # 246.49 MB
print(sys.getsizeof(df)/(1024*1024))  # 30.1 MB
```

And after restarting the kernel:

```
import os
import psutil
import sys

import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df2 = pd.read_csv("example.csv", parse_dates=['crawl_ts', 'market_ts'])

process = psutil.Process()
print(df2.shape)  # (195976, 6)
print(process.memory_info().rss/(1024*1024))  # 112.9 MB
print(sys.getsizeof(df2)/(1024*1024))  # 30.1 MB
```

The dataset I loaded contains almost 200,000 entries. I did the same experiment using 25k, 50k, 75k, and 100k entries. The results of the total memory required is shown below:

```
|   N Rows |   Total Memory pd.read_sql() |   Total Memory pd.read_csv() |   Abs Diff |   Diff Increase |
|---------:|-----------------------------:|-----------------------------:|-----------:|----------------:|
|   100000 |                       172.77 |                      101.676 |    71.0942 |         18.3342 |
|    75000 |                       151.3  |                       98.54  |    52.76   |         17.1    |
|    50000 |                       130.26 |                       94.6   |    35.66   |         18.37   |
|    25000 |                       108.56 |                       91.27  |    17.29   |        nan      |
```

From this table, we can see that for every extra 25,000 rows, the approach using `pd.read_sql()` requires an additional 18 megabytes. Now if we extrapolate this result for 1 million rows, the `pd.read_sql()` approach requires 720 MBs more than the `pd.read_csv()` approach for this dataset. The dataset I used only contained 6 columns - the difference will of course also increase when datasets with more columns are loaded!

**Additional Info: `df.info()` for both datasets showing dataset parity**

`df.info()` for df (created using `pd.read_sql()`)

```
print(df.info())
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 195976 entries, 0 to 195975
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column           Non-Null Count   Dtype         
---  ------           --------------   -----         
 0   crawl_ts         195976 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 1   crawler_version  195976 non-null  object        
 2   ticker           195976 non-null  object        
 3   market_ts        195976 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 4   bid              195976 non-null  float64       
 5   ask              195976 non-null  float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(2), object(2)
memory usage: 9.0+ MB
None
```

`df.info()` for df2 (created using `pd.read_csv()`)

```
print(df2.info())
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 195976 entries, 0 to 195975
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column           Non-Null Count   Dtype         
---  ------           --------------   -----         
 0   crawl_ts         195976 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 1   crawler_version  195976 non-null  object        
 2   ticker           195976 non-null  object        
 3   market_ts        195976 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 4   bid              195976 non-null  float64       
 5   ask              195976 non-null  float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(2), object(2)
memory usage: 9.0+ MB
None
```

Comment: @topsail I've just updated my answer based on your comments. First, datasets in both approaches require the same amount of memory when assuring dtype parity. Second, I ran the same analysis for different dataset sizes and we can see that the difference increases proportionally - this corroborates the previously implicit assumption that more data requires more overhead when using `pd.read_sql()`

Comment: @topsail I've added the `df.info()` for both datasets; in short the data revolves around typical stock market data with bid and ask information and some timestamps.

Comment: hmmm. Well when I have time I will investigate too. Its interesting. But I feel I should point out that saving time by 1) querying the database and loading a dataframe, then 2) saving the dataframe to csv, then 3) reloading from dataframe from csv ... well this does not actually eliminate the time spent querying the database (step 1 still has to happen). But it could be useful if you were repeating step 1 a lot for some reason -- you could think of it as a type of caching. Also its unclear if this explains the reason for the "slower" query ... more memory doesn't necessarily mean 5-10x longer.