# How does the Pyshark generator work in continuous mode?

Tags: python-3.x, memory-management, generator, wireshark, pyshark

*Background:*

I have created a project in which I capture a .pcapng file via Wireshark *and then* run a set of analyses on it in Python utilizing the Pyshark package before sending it to a Postgres db. I would love to convert the arcitecture to continuously sniff packets and perform analyses instead of capturing via Wireshark *then* processing.

*Question:*

In the event that my (spaghetti) code related to analysis cannot keep up with the influx of packets, what are the consqeuences in Pyshark? I do not know how the generator implementation in *sniff_continuously()* works (nor do I fully understand generators, generally). Where does this backlog of captured packets get collected (in memory, on disk, passed / dropped, etc.). In the event these packets are stored in memory, what are the consequences of accumulating beyond available memory (or what other things should I watch out for)?

*Testing:*

I ran a quick script using Pyshark that continuously sniffed all packets coming in on Eternet and printed the current machine time, the packet sniff time, and memory utilized (via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938733/total-memory-used-by-python-process) SO post) with a time delay which would allow packets to "accumulate".

From what I can tell Pyshark is not dropping packets (as the packet sniff time is incrementing ever so slightly while machine time is marching forward using a delay. This would cause me to believe that the sniffed packets are being "stored" somewhere. My rolling average memory usage is increasing slightly - is this the case? [(graph here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bo5g2.png)

Please see below the code used for my testing purposes:

```
import os, psutil, pyshark, time
from datetime import datetime

process = psutil.Process()

capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='Ethernet')
print('Current Machine Time, Packet Sniff Time, Memory Utilized')

for packet in capture.sniff_continuously():

    print(f'{time.time()}, {datetime.fromtimestamp(float(packet.sniff_timestamp))}, {process.memory_info().rss}')  # in bytes
    time.sleep(5)
```

Thank you