# /usr/bin/time always give 0 for average resident set size

Tags: linux

I am trying to use /usr/bin/time to collect the average resident set size of programs. I tried this command with several programs but the average resident set size is always zero. For example:

[image: /usr/bin/time result]

My OS is ubuntu 10.04.

Could you please tell me what is the reason or how I can fix it? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look, `/usr/bin/time` does not calculate this data itself. It uses `wait4` to get this data from Linux. This is a description of wait4:

```
>man wait4

       pid_t wait4(pid_t pid, int *status, int options,
                   struct rusage *rusage);
```

The problem is that not all fields in `struct ruusage` are maintained:

> ```
>    Not all fields are completed; unmaintained fields are set to zero by
>    the kernel.  (The unmaintained fields are provided for compatibility
>    with other systems, and because they may one day be supported on
>    Linux.)  The fields are interpreted as follows:
> ```

While maxrss is mantained other fields about rss are not. So it just returns returns 0 and /usr/bin/time also prints 0.

Moreover, if you take a look at source files of GNU time you will see this code:

```
/*
FMT is the format string, interpreted as described above.
*/
static void
summarize (fp, fmt, command, resp)
     FILE *fp;
     const char *fmt;
     const char **command;
     RESUSE *resp;
{

  while (*fmt)
    {
      switch (*fmt)
    {

        case 'M':       /* Maximum resident set size.  */
          fprintf (fp, "%lu", ptok ((UL) resp->ru.ru_maxrss));
          break;

        case 't':       /* Average resident set size.  */
          fprintf (fp, "%lu",
               MSEC_TO_TICKS (v) == 0 ? 0 :
               ptok ((UL) resp->ru.ru_idrss) / MSEC_TO_TICKS (v));
```

Since ru_idrss is returned by Linux as 0 then average resident set size is 0.

Useful links:

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html
- [Is getrusage broken in Linux (2.6.30)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205806/is-getrusage-broken-in-linux-2-6-30)
- http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/time/