# How to get minor and major page fault for individual or group of processes?

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to write a code in Linux C. Basically I am trying to draw a statistic that should show like: `pid, number of process, page fault(major/minor)  and total number of page faults.`

```
val, pid, pagefault, number of processes, total number of pages faults(Majpr+Minor)

1     127    major           1                          2323
```

for an idea I took the code solution from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188170/generate-major-page-faults and its code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
  struct stat stats;
  fstat(fd, &stats);
  posix_fadvise(fd, 0, stats.st_size, POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED);
  char * map = (char *) mmap(NULL, stats.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
  if (map == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("Failed to mmap");
    return 1;
  }
  int result = 0;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < stats.st_size; i++) {
    result += map[i];
  }
  munmap(map, stats.st_size);
  return result;
}
```

this code does but giving too much things. I also saw this link sol: [Measure page faults from a c program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302763/measure-page-faults-from-a-c-program) 
but failed to make my way that how shd i get the page faults(Major/Minor). Anyone who can tell me how to get major and minor faults?

Comment: Maybe you had a better chance on the [unix SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: unix SE. whats SE ??????

Comment: stackexchange. This wonderful voting up - voting down - voting out in hird engine.

Comment: now since i have posted then now how shd i transfer to stackexchange?

Comment: Click the "edit" link, copy the text of your question, go to http://unix.stackexchange.com (similar site as this, from the same company, but with a little bit different outlook and rules), ask new question, paste into the textbox. But it looks your question finally wasn't closed (= moderated out), maybe it will even get an useful answer.