# Calculating computational time and memory for a code in python

Tags: python

Can some body help me as how to find how much time and how much memory does it take for a code in python?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897941/python-equivalent-of-phps-memory-get-usage) for calculating total memory used.

Answer (score 15):

Use this for calculating time:

```
import time

time_start = time.clock()
#run your code
time_elapsed = (time.clock() - time_start)
```

As referenced by the Python documentation:

> **time.clock()**
>
> On Unix, return the current processor time as a floating
>   point number expressed in seconds. The precision, and in fact the very
>   definition of the meaning of “processor time”, depends on that of the
>   C function of the same name, but in any case, this is the function to
>   use for benchmarking Python or timing algorithms.
>
> On Windows, this function returns wall-clock seconds elapsed since the
>   first call to this function, as a floating point number, based on the
>   Win32 function QueryPerformanceCounter(). The resolution is typically
>   better than one microsecond.

**Reference**: http://docs.python.org/library/time.html

---

Use this for calculating memory:

```
import resource

resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
```

**Reference**: http://docs.python.org/library/resource.html

Comment: This will get his time but not memory used.

Comment: thanx...i am using python in windows and i think the memory calculation u described is for linux??

Comment: import resource

resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss

Comment: This gives an error in python (windows)                                       ,import resource

resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss

Comment: `time.clock()` has been depricated. Use `time.perf_counter()` or `time.process_time()`.

Answer (score 9):

Based on [@Daniel Li's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11886898/1497139) for cut&paste convenience and Python 3.x compatibility:

```
import time
import resource 

time_start = time.perf_counter()
# insert code here ...
time_elapsed = (time.perf_counter() - time_start)
memMb=resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss/1024.0/1024.0
print ("%5.1f secs %5.1f MByte" % (time_elapsed,memMb))
```

**Example:**

```
 2.3 secs 140.8 MByte
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a really good library called [jackedCodeTimerPy](https://github.com/BebeSparkelSparkel/jackedCodeTimerPY) for timing your code. You should then use resource package that Daniel Li suggested.

jackedCodeTimerPy gives really good reports like

```
label            min          max         mean        total    run count
-------  -----------  -----------  -----------  -----------  -----------
imports  0.00283813   0.00283813   0.00283813   0.00283813             1
loop     5.96046e-06  1.50204e-05  6.71864e-06  0.000335932           50
```

I like how it gives you statistics on it and the number of times the timer is run.

It's simple to use. If i want to measure the time code takes in a for loop i just do the following:

```
from jackedCodeTimerPY import JackedTiming
JTimer = JackedTiming()

for i in range(50):
  JTimer.start('loop')  # 'loop' is the name of the timer
  doSomethingHere = 'This is really useful!'
  JTimer.stop('loop')
print(JTimer.report())  # prints the timing report
```

You can can also have multiple timers running at the same time.

```
JTimer.start('first timer')
JTimer.start('second timer')
do_something = 'amazing'
JTimer.stop('first timer')

do_something = 'else'
JTimer.stop('second timer')

print(JTimer.report())  # prints the timing report
```

There are more use example in the repo. Hope this helps.

https://github.com/BebeSparkelSparkel/jackedCodeTimerPY

Answer (score 1):

Use a memory profiler like guppy

```
>>> from guppy import hpy; h=hpy()
>>> h.heap()
Partition of a set of 48477 objects. Total size = 3265516 bytes.
Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0  25773  53  1612820  49   1612820  49 str
     1  11699  24   483960  15   2096780  64 tuple
     2    174   0   241584   7   2338364  72 dict of module
     3   3478   7   222592   7   2560956  78 types.CodeType
     4   3296   7   184576   6   2745532  84 function
     5    401   1   175112   5   2920644  89 dict of class
     6    108   0    81888   3   3002532  92 dict (no owner)
     7    114   0    79632   2   3082164  94 dict of type
     8    117   0    51336   2   3133500  96 type
     9    667   1    24012   1   3157512  97 __builtin__.wrapper_descriptor
<76 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
>>> h.iso(1,[],{})
Partition of a set of 3 objects. Total size = 176 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0      1  33      136  77       136  77 dict (no owner)
     1      1  33       28  16       164  93 list
     2      1  33       12   7       176 100 int
>>> x=[]
>>> h.iso(x).sp
 0: h.Root.i0_modules['__main__'].__dict__['x']
```