# Python script knows how much memory it's using

Tags: python, memory-management

How can a python script know the amount of system memory it's currently using? (assuming a unix-based OS)

Answer (score 11):

If you want to know the total memory that the interpreter uses, on Linux, read [`/proc/self/statm`](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl5_proc.htm).

If you want to find out how much memory your objects use, use [Pympler](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pympler/0.1).

Answer (score 4):

Similar question:

[Python memory profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/python-memory-profiler)

Looks like there are memory profilers for python.

PySizer seems popular. 
Heapy is another.

Google: "python memory profiler" for more.

Comment: +1 - very similar. I think this question could be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

I've used once snippet I found on  [ActiveState](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/286222/) and it seemed to work well.
Actually it's using same method Martin v. Löwis suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a simple way to do this. As a practical matter, on a Unix OS I'd probably do something with os.getpid() and calling ps or reading entries in /proc.

Python 2.6 adds sys.getsizeof(), which you could use in concert with gc.get_objects() to walk the size of the working set of objects:

```
>>> print sum([sys.getsizeof(o) for o in gc.get_objects()])
561616
```

I don't think that'd be a good idea in practice.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, but you might take a look at **heapy** (http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/#Heapy), which looks to be a memory profiler for python programs.