# Tornado doesn't free memory after many connections for downloading

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I have some problems with freeing memory in Tornado. My handler downloading part of big bytes file, and write it in response. But the more parallel requests the more memory is used (this is logical). But after the end of requests, memory is not free!

My code:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.gen
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient, HTTPRequest


AsyncHTTPClient.configure("tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient", max_clients=50)


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        url = "http://example.com/big_bytes_file"
        request = HTTPRequest(url, headers={'Range': 'bytes=0-1048576'}, method='GET')
        client = AsyncHTTPClient()
        range_resp = yield client.fetch(request)
        self.write(range_resp.body)


def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([(r"/", MainHandler), ])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(5000)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

What I do?

1. I'm see memory usage after start application (111 MB):
   [memory after start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3fp2.jpg)
2. Sending one request. Memory increase (114 MB): [114 MB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYP7k.jpg)
3. Sending parallel requests from 25 users. Memory - 123 MB.
4. Sending parallel requests from 50 users. Memory - 153 MB.
5. Sending parallel requests from 100 users. Memory - 205 MB.
6. Waiting a few minutes. Memory not decrease.

Why is that? :)

P.S. An example, we send requests from 80 users. After this memory increase. After that, the memory will increase only if the users is more than 80.

Comment: In general, you should not expect a garbage collector to release memory unless it has to. As you see in your 80 user test, memory is not leaked but available for reuse. You should only be worried if memory consumption increases without workload increasing as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are all Python objects tracked by the garbage collector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079171/are-all-python-objects-tracked-by-the-garbage-collector)

Comment: I used gc.collect() - memory not decrease.

Comment: The interpreter owns memory, not objects. Using ``gc.collect`` will only finalise (destroy) the objects, not necessarily release their memory. See the answer to the linked question for some details on how the CPython gc manages memory arenas.

Comment: This is not a memory leak, as already pointed out by MisterMiyagi. But to clear out some memory, you can try `del range_resp` after `self.write` line and see if that works.

Comment: I tried to remove range_resp. It doesn't help.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, how I can clear out the memory?

Comment: Look, it is pretty obvious that you have little idea how a garbage collector works. You *cannot* and even if you could, you *should not*. The GC takes care of that memory and will reuse or release it if required. There is also the problem that you are looking at a misleading memory metric to begin with...

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, for 100 users it is OK. But for 1000 users - uses ALL available memory - and application not work.

Comment: @Student Then you simply have not enough memory to handle 1000 users, full stop. The GC is already reusing the memory of previous requests.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, But in the case: 

**range_resp = yield [client.fetch(request) for _ in range(200)]**

**del range_resp**

I'm sending ONE request - memory increase and don't release. In this case, Tornado also caches memory for reuse?