# memory leak, size of objects tracked by gc is far less than memory usage of process

Tags: python, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Our object is a big system.
As we know there must be some memory leak in it by now. But it is so difficult to find the reason. Everytime memory used by the process reaches gigabytes, the response of it is so slow.
cpu usage viewed from "top" is alwasy 100%, even the process has no job to do.

We have used objgraph and meliae to debug this problem, nothing to suspect. But we found one weird problem, the total size of objects got by gc.get_objects() is not equal with the memory usage viewed from "top", for example it is 50M, but 150M from "top".

Could anyone give us a direction? Thanks.

Comment: The first likely culprit is any C/Non-Python extensions you are using since they require manual memory management.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you're getting the size of objects with something like this:

```
sum(sys.getsizeof(i) for i in gc.get_objects())
```

Remember that the result of `gc.get_objects()` doesn't include memory consumed by the interpreter itself, only Python objects tracked by the garbage collector. Also, this function relies on objects returning accurate results from their `__sizeof__()` method, so if you're using any third party modules then you can't necessarily expect accurate results.

You may have already done this, but you can have your application periodically call `gc.collect()` and then check `gc.garbage` to see if you've got any unreachable objects that the collector couldn't free. This will be the case if you have any classes with circular reference on which you've overridden `__del__()` (see [Python docs for gc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html?highlight=gc#gc.garbage)).

I would also suggest adding this call to the start of your code:

```
gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_UNCOLLECTABLE | gc.DEBUG_INSTANCES | gc.DEBUG_OBJECTS)
```

This will print messages to `stderr` whenever objects are found with circular references and the like. This might give you useful information on where to look more closely.

So far these sorts of problems would have likely been picked up by objgraph, though, but it might be worth putting them in anyway because you can leave them active in a long-running daemon to get a record over time of when such issues occurred.

If you're using any C extensions (either that you've written yourself or third party ones) then carefully check the code for errors in handling reference counts - it's fairly easy to make a mistake there. Also, bear in mind that there's nothing to stop extensions allocating their own memory outside of Python's allocators - in this case nothing you do within the Python interpreter will detect it if these leak.

All that said, if you're still seeing memory usage monotonically increasing and you can't find any Python objects that are the cause then it's probably time to check for leaks in lower-level C code or the Python interpreter itself - a good tool for this is [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

To use Valgrind with Python you'll want to use [the Python suppression file](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/4617b7ac302a/Misc/valgrind-python.supp). You might find this is already installed - Ubuntu places a modified form of this file in `/usr/lib/valgrind/python.supp`, for example.

To do this properly, you'll want to recompile Python as described in the [README.valgrind](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/4617b7ac302a/Misc/README.valgrind) file in the Python distribution, but you might find you get some interesting results even without this.

There's more discussion about running Python under Valgrind in [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982036/how-can-i-use-valgrind-with-python-c-extensions).

Comment: Thank you, Cartroo. After gc.collect(), gc.garbage() did get something unreachable before, and we have resolved that. The third party modules we used include "twisted". Ok, now we will try to find the problem in twisted and python itself.

Comment: It looks like [you're not the only person to see leaks in Twisted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078084/memory-leak-in-python-twisted-where-is-it). In the past I've had to do staggered automated restarts of services (one redundant server at a time) when I've had issues like this in third party software and no time to track them down. At least that's a workaround that might reduce the impact of the problem.