# Python order of execution

Tags: python, execution

I was wondering if Python has similar issues as C regarding the order of execution of certain elements of code.

For example, I know in C there are times say when it's not guaranteed that some variable is initialized before another. Or just because one line of code is above another it's not guaranteed that it is implemented before all the ones below it.

Is it the same for Python? Like if I open a file of data, read in the data, close the file, then do other stuff do I know for sure that the file is closed before the lines after I close the file are executed??

The reason I ask is because I'm trying to read in a large file of data (1.6GB) and use this python module specific to the work I do on the data. When I run this module I get this error message:

```
    File "/glast01/software/ScienceTools/ScienceTools-v9r15p2-SL4/sane/v3r18p1/python/GtApp.py", line 57, in run
    input, output = self.runWithOutput(print_command)
  File "/glast01/software/ScienceTools/ScienceTools-v9r15p2-SL4/sane/v3r18p1/python/GtApp.py", line 77, in runWithOutput
    return os.popen4(self.command(print_command))
  File "/Home/eud/jmcohen/.local/lib/python2.5/os.py", line 690, in popen4
    stdout, stdin = popen2.popen4(cmd, bufsize)
  File "/Home/eud/jmcohen/.local/lib/python2.5/popen2.py", line 199, in popen4
    inst = Popen4(cmd, bufsize)
  File "/Home/eud/jmcohen/.local/lib/python2.5/popen2.py", line 125, in __init__
    self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
>>> 
Exception exceptions.AttributeError: AttributeError("Popen4 instance has no attribute 'pid'",) in <bound method Popen4.__del__ of <popen2.Popen4 instance at 0x9ee6fac>> ignored
```

I assume it's related to the size of the data I read in (it has 17608310 rows and 22 columns). 
I thought perhaps if I closed the file I opened right after I read in the data this would help, but it didn't. This led me to thinking about the order that lines of code are executed in, hence my question.

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to explain yourself better.  In C, given `f(); g();`, `f()` is guaranteed to be evaluated before `g()` is.  In `a = f() + g();`, the order of evaluation is unspecified in C.  Python guarantees left-to-right evaluation: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order

Comment: by 'issues' you mean 'rules', right?

Comment: Yeah, I knew I wasn't explaining myself well,  sorry, it comes from not fully understanding all this but trying too :)

Alok: Yes, that's essentially what I was thinking. I thought it also carried over to things like when a file might get closed. I know I can say define two different functions and call the 2nd one (by 2nd I just mean lower down in the code) from the first, so in that sense too it's not necessarily done in order.

kevindtimm: Yes, I meant rules. I guess i just used the work issues because it's giving me trouble :)

Comment: @Jamie: Please do not write extensive, hard-to-read comments on your own question.  Please fix your question and delete your comments.  You own the question, you can edit it until it's clear.

Comment: Why should closing the file affect memory consumption? If you read 1.6G worth of data all at once into whatever memory structure you have designed (which may be highly nonoptimal for all we know), freeing one little file handle won't change anything. Do you really have to load the entire file in memory, or can you work through the file line by line?

Comment: an open file consumes an insignificant amount of memory. You should ask a question about your memory usage, not worrying about whether python will rearrange your code.

Answer (score 12):

The only thing I can think of that may surprise some people is:

```
def test():
    try:
        return True
    finally:
        return False

print test()
```

Output:

```
False
```

`finally` clauses really are executed last, even if a `return` statement precedes them. However, this is not specific to Python.

Answer (score 3):

Execution of C certainly is sequential, for actual statements. There are even rules that define the [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point), so you can know how individual expressions evaluate.

Answer (score 3):

CPython itself is written in such a way that any effects like those you mention are minimized; code always executes top to bottom barring literal evaluation during compilation, objects are GCed as soon as their refcount hits 0, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Execution in the cpython vm is very linear. I do not think whatever problem you have has to do with order of execution.

One thing you should be careful about in Python but not C: exceptions can be raised everywhere, so just because you see a `close()` call below the corresponding `open()` call does not mean that call is actually reached. Use `try`/`finally` everywhere (or the `with` statement in new enough pythons) to make sure opened files are closed (and other kinds of resources that can be freed explicitly are freed).

If your problem is with memory usage, not some other kind of resource, debugging it can be harder. Memory cannot be freed explicitly in python. The cpython vm (which you are most likely using) does release memory as soon as the last reference to it goes away, but sometimes cannot free memory trapped in cycles with objects that have a `__del__` method. If you have any `__del__` methods of your own or use classes that have them this may be part of your problem.

Your actual question (the memory one, not the order of execution one) is hard to answer without seeing more code, though. It may be something obvious (or there may at least be some obvious way to reduce the amount of memory you need).

Answer (score 1):

"if I open a file of data, read in the data, close the file, then do other stuff do I know for sure that the file is closed before the lines after I close the file are executed??"

Closed yes.

Released from memory.  No.  No guarantees about when garbage collection will occur.

Further, closing a file says nothing about all the other variables you've created and the other objects you've left laying around attached to those variables.

There's no "order of operations" issue.

I'll bet that you have too many global variables with too many copies of the data.

Answer (score 0):

If the data consists of columns and rows, why not use the built in file iterator to fetch one line at a time?

```
f = open('file.txt')
first_line = f.next()
```

Answer (score 0):

[popen2.py](http://svn.python.org/view/python/tags/r25/Lib/popen2.py?view=markup#Popen4):

```
class Popen4(Popen3):
    childerr = None

    def __init__(self, cmd, bufsize=-1):
        _cleanup()
        self.cmd = cmd
        p2cread, p2cwrite = os.pipe()
        c2pread, c2pwrite = os.pipe()
        self.pid = os.fork()
        if self.pid == 0:
            # Child
            os.dup2(p2cread, 0)
            os.dup2(c2pwrite, 1)
            os.dup2(c2pwrite, 2)
            self._run_child(cmd)
        os.close(p2cread)
        self.tochild = os.fdopen(p2cwrite, 'w', bufsize)
        os.close(c2pwrite)
        self.fromchild = os.fdopen(c2pread, 'r', bufsize)
```

[man 2 fork](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fork.html):

> The *fork()* function may fail if:
>
> [ENOMEM]
>         Insufficient storage space is available.

`os.popen4` eventually calls `open2.Popen4.__init__`, which must `fork` in order to create the child process that you try to read from/write to.  This underlying call is failing, likely due to resource exhaustion.

You may be using too much memory elsewhere, causing `fork` to attempt to use more than the [RLIMIT_DATA](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getrlimit.html) or RLIMIT_RSS limit given to your user.  As recommended by [Python memory profiler - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259), [Heapy](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/#Heapy) can help you determine whether this is the case.