# What is the Python 'buffer' type for?

Tags: python, python-2.7

There is a `buffer` type in Python, but how can I use it?

In the [Python documentation about `buffer()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#buffer), the description is:

> `buffer(object[, offset[, size]])`

The object argument must be an object that supports the buffer call interface (such as strings, arrays, and buffers). A new buffer object will be created which references the object argument. The buffer object will be a slice from the beginning of object (or from the specified offset). The slice will extend to the end of object (or will have a length given by the size argument).

Answer (score 161, accepted):

An example usage:

```
>>> s = 'Hello world'
>>> t = buffer(s, 6, 5)
>>> t
<read-only buffer for 0x10064a4b0, size 5, offset 6 at 0x100634ab0>
>>> print t
world
```

The buffer in this case is a sub-string, starting at position 6 with length 5, and it doesn't take extra storage space - it references a slice of the string.

This isn't very useful for short strings like this, but it can be necessary when using large amounts of data. This example uses a mutable `bytearray`:

```
>>> s = bytearray(1000000)   # a million zeroed bytes
>>> t = buffer(s, 1)         # slice cuts off the first byte
>>> s[1] = 5                 # set the second element in s
>>> t[0]                     # which is now also the first element in t!
'\x05'
```

This can be very helpful if you want to have more than one view on the data and don't want to (or can't) hold multiple copies in memory.

Note that [`buffer`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#buffer) has been replaced by the better named [`memoryview`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) in Python 3, though you can use either in Python 2.7.

Note also that you can't implement a buffer interface for your own objects without delving into the C API, i.e. you can't do it in pure Python.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But I still don't quite understand what's the difference between buffering and simple slicing. Using `s[6:11]` doesn't take extra storage space either, am I wrong?

Comment: In general a slice will take extra storage, so yes `s[6:11]` will be a copy. If you set `t = s[6:11]` and then `del s`, it frees the memory that was taken by `s`, proving that `t` was copied. (To see this you need a bigger `s` and track Python's memory usage). It is however much more efficient just to make the copy if there isn't much data involved.

Comment: Thank you very mush :) BTW, could you please tell me what tool can I use to track Python's memory usage?

Comment: For memory usage see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/ for example. Sometimes it's easiest just to watch Python's usage in Task Manager/Activity Monitor/top.

Comment: For Python noobs like me: buffer is memoryview in Python 3

Comment: To investigate how python does a slice and whether it makes a copy or not, you could do a dis.dis (using the dis module) on a function that does something like: s = "123123123" t = s[:3]. Then you will see the SLICE+2 operator, and further reading on it will give you the answer that it does actually make a copy.

Comment: @ScottGriffiths : Is there a way to make the data returned by buffer writeable without copying *(thus modyfing the original value of`s`in the example of your answer)* ?

Comment: @user2284570: The data in the buffer is writeable if the original object is mutable. So for strings you can't modify them, but in the second example I show how a buffer into a mutable `bytearray` can be used to modify the original.

Comment: @ScottGriffiths : **If I understand you correctly you made an error then**. In the second example, you’re showing how the bytearray is writable not how the buffer is writable.

Comment: @user2284570: I should have said instead that modifying the mutable original modifies the buffer also - just try it in the Python interpreter. Your 'correction' causes an error when you try to modify the buffer so I've rolled it back.

Answer (score 30):

I think buffers are e.g. useful when interfacing Python to native libraries ([Guido van Rossum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_van_Rossum) explains `buffer` in [this mailing list post](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2000-October/009974.html)).

For example, [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) seems to use buffer for efficient data storage:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.ndarray(1000000)
```

The `a.data` is a:

```
<read-write buffer for 0x1d7b410, size 8000000, offset 0 at 0x1e353b0>
```