# Python str view

Tags: python, memory, python-3.x, python-2.x

I have a huge `str` of ~1GB in length:

```
>>> len(L)
1073741824
```

I need to take many pieces of the string from specific indexes until the end of the string. In C I'd do:

```
char* L = ...;
char* p1 = L + start1;
char* p2 = L + start2;
...
```

But in Python, slicing a string creates a new `str` instance using more memory:

```
>>> id(L)
140613333131280
>>> p1 = L[10:]
>>> id(p1)
140612259385360
```

To save memory, how do I create an str-like object that is in fact a pointer to the original L?

**Edit**: we have `buffer` and `memoryview` in Python 2 and Python 3, but `memoryview` does not exhibit the same interface as an `str` or `bytes`:

```
>>> L = b"0" * 1000
>>> a = memoryview(L)
>>> b = memoryview(L)
>>> a < b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: memoryview() < memoryview()

>>> type(b'')
<class 'bytes'>
>>> b'' < b''
False
>>> b'0' < b'1'
True
```

Comment: Can't you just do `id(L[10:])` instead of making a new variable?

Comment: @Iplodman That still creates a new str slice, using memory, and then discards the temporary slice.

Comment: python has a buffer type see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422685/what-is-python-buffer-type-for

Comment: @gabber There is no buffer() in Python 3. The replacement is memoryview which is not exactly the same, does not behaves like a bytes str.

Comment: @vz0 I think I forgot to reply (sorry!) I'm not exactly a Python guru, so thanks!

Comment: I am baffled how such a large and "batteries-included" language doesn't provide an out-of-the-box solution to your quite basic and often encountered question!

Comment: You asked for a "str-like object" but you've tagged both Python 2 and Python 3.  Could you clarify whether you want a **Python 2 str-like object** or a **Python 3 str-like object**?

Answer (score 7):

There is a [`memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) type:

```
>>> v = memoryview('potato')
>>> v[2]
't'
>>> v[-1]
'o'
>>> v[1:4]
<memory at 0x7ff0876fb808>
>>> v[1:4].tobytes()
'ota'
```

Comment: Perhaps your answer should be edited to use bytes so that it will also work in python 3. Either that or remove the 3.x tag from the question.

Comment: My problem is that once it's a bytes literal, you get silly ints for `v[2]` etc. That would make the edit non-trivial. Unless you meant the question :D

Comment: Use slicing then

Comment: @AnttiHaapala  slicing always creates a copy, no?

Answer (score 4):

If you need to work on a string, use iterators to actually access the data without duplicating the content in memory

Your tool of trade would be [itertools.tee](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) and [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

```
>>> L = "Random String of data"
>>> p1, p2 = tee(L)
>>> p1 = islice(p1,10,None)
>>> p2 = islice(p2,15,None)
>>> ''.join(p1) # This now creates a copy now
'ing of data'
>>> ''.join(p2) # This now creates a copy now
'f data'
```

This in literal sense yield a pointer, unlike in C/C++, it is just a forward pointer/iterator

**Note** Off-course you need to take due diligence in using the forward iterators namely

1. To save the pointer before advancing. `itertools.tee` would be useful here as in `p1, p_saved = tee(p1)`
2. You can read as a character `next(p1)` or as a string `''.join(p1)`, but because python string is not mutable, every time you need a string view, you would be presented as a copy.
3. As you can read as a single characters, all your algorithms should leverage the iterable capabilities rather than generating the string. For example to compare two itertors, instead of comparing the content `''.join(p1) == ''.join(p2)`, you need to do the following `all(a == b for a, b in izip(p1, p2))`

Comment: @vz0: It seems, my answer is still valid after your edit

Comment: No it does not. You can not compare < two tee or islice objects.

Comment: @vz0: Yes you can. `all(a == b for a, b in izip(p1, p2))`

Comment: That is not the less than "<" operation.

Comment: @vz0: For less than operator, replace `==` with `<`. If required use izip_longest instead of izip. I am not getting where you want to take this?

Comment: This is not a "str-like" object. As my question says, I want to use something that looks like a normal string taken as a slice of a bigger string. With your approach I have to rethink and rewrite all the string operations again in Pure python. In C is as easy as taking a pointer from the start of the char*.

Comment: @vz0: Actually you have to create a wrapper ( a class with all methods of string) and use that wrapper everywhere instead of the string. This seems to be a trivial extension of the idea , so am really wondering now, where is this going to

Comment: @vz0 There is no such thing as a pointer in python, we have only namespaces (mapping names <-> objects) and of course strings are immutable.  If you want pointers, use C.

Comment: I think this may not be a good alternative because, literally "This itertool may require significant auxiliary storage".

Comment: If you're going to make a wrapper class, there's no point in using iterators at all: you can make a namedtuple with the original string and two offsets into it.