# passing Array[Byte] from ironpython to python using pickle

Tags: python, clr, ironpython, pickle

I recently started programming macros for a microscope that is controlled by ZEN Blue from Zeiss. The Zeiss macro environment uses IronPython 2.7.2.1. I need to write out a hdf5 file, but unfortunately hdf5 support for IronPython is quite bad.

The data I want to transfer is of type Array[Byte] which seems to be somehow connected to the CLR of .NET:

```
print "length: %i type: %s" %(len(data), type(data))
```

gives:

```
length: 4915200 type: <type 'Array[Byte]'>
```

I can sucessfully transfer a dict containing ints and Strings to a python server using pickle via a socket connection (suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.duapp.com/questions/11458033/passing-pickle-between-python-and-ironpython)). However, when I try to unpickle the `Array[Byte]` data, python wants to import the CLR, which of course fails:

```
ImportError: No module named clr
```

**Question:** What is the best (fastest) way to convert the .NET Array[Byte] to a basic python type/object which is not linked to the .NET clr?

many thanks,
Dominic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, the most efficient solution that I found works like this:

First, convert Array[Byte] to a python string:

```
data_str = str(buffer(data))
```

I'm not entirely sure what `buffer` does, but it seems to be necessary for efficient computation, some explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422685/what-is-python-buffer-type-for).

Then send to cpython (in my case via a socket, cpython runs on a linux box) and convert to a tuple:

```
#data_str is an RGB image with dims sx and sy
format_str = str(sx*sy*3).strip() + 'B' 
im_data = struct.unpack(format_str, data_str) #conversion to tuple
```

Finally, use `numpy` and `h5py` to write the `.h5` file:

```
#put into np.array
im = np.asarray(im_data, dtype=np.uint8) #this is the most Time consuming part
newshape = (3, sx, sy)
im = np.reshape(im, newshape, order='F')

#write out
f = h5py.File('zenimage_bgr24.h5', 'w')
f.create_dataset('/im', data = im, dtype='uint8')
f.close()
```