# Buffer function for python 3+

Tags: python, python-3.x, buffer, vtk

I'm trying to open a vtk window using vtk_show, but my Ipython console crashes every time i do this, apparently this is because Ipython can't display an external window, which is exactly what vtk_show does. I searched on google for a solution, but it's written for python2 (i'm using python 3.6.3). Here's the solution i found:

```
import vtk
from IPython.display import Image

def vtk_show(renderer, width=400, height=300):
    """
    Takes vtkRenderer instance and returns an IPython Image with the 
    rendering.
    """
    renderWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
    renderWindow.SetOffScreenRendering(1)
    renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)
    renderWindow.SetSize(width, height)
    renderWindow.Render()

    windowToImageFilter = vtk.vtkWindowToImageFilter()
    windowToImageFilter.SetInput(renderWindow)
    windowToImageFilter.Update()

    writer = vtk.vtkPNGWriter()
    writer.SetWriteToMemory(1)
    writer.SetInputConnection(windowToImageFilter.GetOutputPort())
    writer.Write()
    data = str(buffer(writer.GetResult()))

    return Image(data)
```

I'm getting an error while trying to use the `buffer` built-in function of python2, but as this function doesn't exist on python3+ i'm stuck.. If anyone could help me with this i would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At least these two points must be modified on your code to have the same behavior with Python 3:

- The `buffer(...)` built-in function in Python 2 has been replaced by `memoryview(...)` in Python 3: [What is Python buffer type for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422685/what-is-python-buffer-type-for). Replace the `buffer` call by `memoryview`
- the `str(...)` built-in function has to replaced by a `bytes(...)` call to get a `bytes` object: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/pyporting.html#text-versus-binary-data

So the `data = ...` line should read:

```
data = bytes(memoryview(writer.GetResult()))
```

Comment: What do you mean by it didn’t work? Could you post the error message? Also, could you you precise that in your initial post?

Comment: I think it comes from the str call now. Try to change the line ‘data=...’ in ‘data = memoryview(writer.GetResults()).tobytes()’

Comment: Hey again and sorry for the very late response! i managed to fix the error i was getting and completely forgot to come here.

Comment: No worries! Note that you can answer your own question!

Comment: This worked for fixing the example code for [pyzmq](https://pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/serialization.html) as well.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, I believe this example was an adaptation of a very [informative blog example showing how to extract surfaces from medical images using VTK's marching cubes algorithm](https://pyscience.wordpress.com/2014/09/11/surface-extraction-creating-a-mesh-from-pixel-data-using-python-and-vtk/). The [accompanying Jupyter notebook](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/bitbucket.org/somada141/pyscience/raw/master/20140908_SurfaceExtraction/Material/SurfaceExtractionVTK.ipynb#) was intended for Python 2.7, and as mentioned for it to be used in Python 3.6+, the `data=...` portion needs to be changed.

```
import vtk
from IPython.display import Image

def vtk_show(renderer, width=400, height=300):
    """
    Takes vtkRenderer instance and returns an IPython Image with the 
    rendering.
    """
    renderWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
    renderWindow.SetOffScreenRendering(1)
    renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)
    renderWindow.SetSize(width, height)
    renderWindow.Render()

    windowToImageFilter = vtk.vtkWindowToImageFilter()
    windowToImageFilter.SetInput(renderWindow)
    windowToImageFilter.Update()

    writer = vtk.vtkPNGWriter()
    writer.SetWriteToMemory(1)
    writer.SetInputConnection(windowToImageFilter.GetOutputPort())
    writer.Write()
    data = memoryview(writer.GetResults()).tobytes()

    return Image(data)
```

Credit for the solution definitely goes to @MafiaSkafia and @jcgiret, but I wanted to post a full and final solution.