# How can i fill buffer in python like below node.js buffer

Tags: python, node.js

I am new to python .
I am writing a simple client that send socket buff to a server. 
I fill buff in node.js like below,how can i do the same in python?

```
    var request = new Buffer(length);
    request .writeUInt32BE(command, 0);
    request .writeUInt32BE(length, 4);
    request .writeUInt32BE(seqNo, 8);
```

update , Problem Solved:

```py
    buff = struct.pack(">III",0x123abc,0x123,123)
```

Comment: You can have more info about python buffers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422685/what-is-python-buffer-type-for

Comment: Looks like you are after the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#module-struct) module…

Comment: yes, struct.pack() helps! thanks your reply!