# Why does python thread consume so much memory?

Tags: python, multithreading

Why does python thread consumes so much memory?

I measured that spawning one thread consumes 8 megs of memory, almost as big as a whole new python process!

OS: Ubuntu 10.10

Edit: due to popular demand I'll give some extraneous examples, here it is:

```
from os import getpid
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

def nap():
    print 'sleeping child'
    sleep(999999999)

print getpid()
child_thread = Thread(target=nap)
sleep(999999999)
```

On my box, pmap pid will give 9424K

Now, let's run the child thread:

```
from os import getpid
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

def nap():
    print 'sleeping child'
    sleep(999999999)

print getpid()
child_thread = Thread(target=nap)
child_thread.start()             # <--- ADDED THIS LINE
sleep(999999999)
```

Now pmap pid will give 17620K

So, the cost for the extra thread is 17620K - 9424K = 8196K

ie. 87% of running a whole new separate process!

Now isn't that just, wrong?

Comment: There is no way anyone can answer this unless you give us some idea of what you're trying to do and how.  Code?  Example of use?  Input data?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/python-memory-profiler

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is not Python-specific, and has to do with the separate stack that gets allocated by the OS for every thread. The default maximum stack size on your OS happens to be 8MB.

Note that the 8MB is simply a chunk of address space that gets set aside, with very little memory committed to it initially. Additional memory gets committed to the stack when required, up to the 8MB limit.

The limit can be tweaked using `ulimit -s`, but in this instance I see no reason to do this.

As an aside, `pmap` shows *address space* usage. It isn't a good way to gauge *memory* usage. The two concepts are quite distinct, if related.

Comment: Thanks, you just saved my life @Guido sorry for the blame, I'll praise python on next question.