# limit threads of a program with for loops

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-3.x

i wrote the following code, that runs a command using subprocess method, under 2 for loops,

```
import threading
import subprocess

def do (i,j):
    subprocess.Popen(['python2.7 some_python_code.py {} {}'.format(i,j)],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

z=[]
for i in range (0,50):
    for j in range (0,50):
        t = threading.Thread(target=do, args=(i,j))
        t.start()
        z.append(t)

for t in z:
    t.join()
```

the matter is that it suddenly starts a massive number of python process and eats the entire of my memory, how can i limit the number of threads ?

thanks.

Comment: (1) `subprocess.Popen()` returns immediately while the process is running yet. You must `wait` for it to terminate. (2) For the thread creation look at `ThreadPoolExecutor` to restrict the number of threads.

Comment: i think subprocess.call waits for the result but it's serial process then ,not parallel process. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you use the option **setDaemon** you can improve the issue, I will put here a link to the reference, read the section Daemon vs noDaemon. https://pymotw.com/2/threading/

By default this option is not activated you can activate in the following way:

```
daemon_thread = threading.Thread(name='MyDaemon', target=do_some_stuff)
daemon_thread.setDaemon(True)
```

You can check the following link if the first option doesn't resolve the problem [How to reduce memory usage of threaded python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796654/how-to-reduce-memory-usage-of-threaded-python-code) I hope that the link can help you, good luck!

Comment: thanks alot Jose, the matter is that it runs 50*50 process at the same time .

Comment: Then you need use multiprocessing, thread don't execute jobs in a parallel way, if you want parallel jobs you need used multiprocessing

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `concurrent.futures` - that automatically creates worker pools of the desired size to which tasks as submited in order.

Also, you have to change your `subprocess` call to be blocking - if the `do` function returns immediately, using the pool won't do a thing.

```
import concurrent.futures

import subprocess
import sys

def do (i,j):
    subprocess.Popen(['python2.7 some_python_code.py {} {}'.format(i,j)],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as pool:
    for i in range (0,50):
        for j in range (0,50):
            t = pool.submit(do, i,j)

   for task in concurrent.future.as_completed(pool):
        try:
            result = task.result()
        except Exception as error:
            print(f"Error executing task '{task}': {error}", file=sys.stderr)
```

Comment: `subprocess.Popen()` returns immediately so the task completes while the process runs yet.

Comment: Thanks. I added a paragraph reflecting that - the OP should come up with a fix to that call.