# numpy.who on all of memory

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to track down a possible memory leak in my code, and I want to make sure I'm not leaving stray references to any ndarrays. Does anyone know if it's possible to do something like numpy.who() but for all arrays in memory?

Any other suggestions for finding large memory objects that might be lost would also be appreciated.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6018986/memory-profiler-for-numpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try out [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), although checking Python code with it [is not that trivial](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Misc/README.valgrind)...