# Optimization of memory usage while copying buffers in python

Tags: python, optimization

I have to copy and do some simple processing on file. I can not read whole file to the memory because it is to big. I come up with piece of code which looks like this:

```
buffer = inFile.read(buffer_size)
while len(buffer) > 0:
    outFile.write(buffer)
    simpleCalculations(buffer)
    buffer = inFile.read(buffer_size)
```

simpleCalculations procedure is irrelevant in this context but I am worried about subsequent memory allocations of buffer list. On some hardware configuration memory usage gets very high and that apparently kills the machine. I would like to reuse buffer. Is this posible in python 2.6?

Comment: "On some hardware configuration memory usage gets very high"?  Is it a problem?  Using a lot of memory is normal.  Is something broken?  Is something too slow?  If everything works, you don't have much to worry about.

Comment: @S.Lott It kills the machine. We suspect driver problem but until I prove this application will be blamed.

Comment: Then **update** the question to replace "gets very high" with the **actual** situation: it appears to kill the machine.  That's important.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python memory profiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/python-memory-profiler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any easy way around this. The `file.read()` method just returns a new string each time you call it. On the other hand, you don't really need to worry about running out of memory -- once you assign `buffer` to the newly-read string, the previously-read string no longer has any references to it, so its memory gets freed automatically (see [here](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html#reference-counts) for more details).

Comment: The problem is that if you read a file in a loop the memory is not returned immediately and therefore you will have a spike in memory usage until GC kicks in and frees the memory. That may not be acceptable on low resource systems.

Answer (score 2):

Python being a strictly reference-counted environment, your buffer will be deallocated as soon as you no longer have any references to it.

If you're worried about physical RAM but have spare address space, you could [mmap](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html) your file rather than reading it in a bit at a time.