# measure of the use of the memory with python

Tags: python, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python memory profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/python-memory-profiler)

I wrote a python script that calls functions from another module but uses lots of memory.
Is there a function which could measure the size of the memory used by a piece of code?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried http://pysizer.8325.org/ ?
There is also: http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/#Heapy