# Number of items (models) in a database versus django RAM consumption?

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

I think this is an error in my own django code but just wanted to make sure.

Does the number of rows or models that I have in a database affect my django RAM consumption?
Suppose we had a mysql table called Model. 
My django code only has lazy queryset evals in this form:

```
Models.objects.filter().blah().blah()[:SOME_NUMBER]
```

The SOME_NUMBER remains at a constant, so the data which is being brought to memory is also constant and unrelated to the total number of "Models" (or at least I hope). However, in my processes tab, as my model count increases, the RAM also increases.. To a point where it becomes too high!

Is this meant to be or is something else leading to this? 
Aside from queryset - db calls, what else can lead to high memory consumption & leaks? If there is nothing else, there must be somewhere in my code where I am querying a bunch of models and i'm not aware. My DJANGO_DEBUG settings are off.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have DEBUG=True in your settings?

Comment: No, it's turned off. I know that leads to memory leaks.

Comment: How are you running django? What is your setup?

Comment: Running it with MySql, Mod_Wsgi, apache2, along with nginx reverse proxy for static resources. My entire app has like 6-8 queries, its just that there are a bunch of models. But regardless that should not mean the RAM usage goes up shouldn't it? Since all that model data is stored in disk memory until we query it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you should investigate.  Django isn't guaranteed to generate the most efficient query (and many times it does rather poorly).  The database may not be tuned properly for the query you are sending it, so it takes a long time to return results.

---

**What query is actually getting sent to the database?**
Use `print str(MyModel.objects.filter(...).query)` to see the query that is being built.  You can also turn DEBUG on (which you should in development, it's there for a reason) and run

```
from django.db import connection

print connection.queries
```

**How is that query evaluated in the database?**
Copy the SQL from above and run it directly in the database with `explain <the query>`.  It will output what is going on behind the scenes and how long it takes.  This could reveal, for instance, that you could add an index to a foreign key to improve join performance.  It may be that the database is reasonably fast with a low number of rows, but a complicated query may grow more than linearly with number of rows.

---

You can also use the [Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) to get this information automatically on the pages you view.

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is memory consumption, this is very difficult to speculate about from a small code example like this. To track down the problem you probably need to use a memory profiler in your application.

This stack overflow question on [Which Python Memory Profiler is Recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/110826/1980029) gives a good, concise example using [Heapy](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/#Heapy) that shows how you can print out a memory dump at some point in your code, and get a feel for what type of objects are occupying memory. This should give you a good starting point for tracking down the memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you temporarily delete some rows in the aforementioned table or drop all the other tables to test your hypothesis?