# Is there a way to estimate how much memory a merge operation will require?

Tags: pandas

Given two dataframes A and B, and X amount of shared columns to merge on (B is merged to A), is there a way to pre-calculate/estimate *in real-time* how much memory the operation will require?

Comment: may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259

Comment: Thanks and sorry I forgot to mention that the estimation is needed in real time. Couldn't find a reference to that in that link.

Comment: Then no, not really. Pandas would at least need to keep around column statistics to estimate that (and it doesn't). If your merges are reasonably consistent, you can probably make your own estimation function.