# Out of Memory Killer activated for python script running a multiprocessing Queue?

Tags: python, queue, out-of-memory, multiprocessing, kill-process

I have written a python program that needs to run for multiple days at a time, because of the constant collection of data.  Previously I had no issues running this program for months at a time.  I recently made some updates to the program, and now after around 12 hours I get the dreaded out of memory killer. The 'dmesg' output is the following:

```
[9084334.914808] Out of memory: Kill process 2276 (python2.7) score 698 or sacrifice child
[9084334.914811] Killed process 2276 (python2.7) total-vm:13279000kB, anon-rss:4838164kB, file-rss:8kB
```

Besides just general python coding, the main change made to the program was the addition of a multiprocessing Queue.  This is the first time I have ever used this feature, so I am not sure if this might be the cause of the issue.  The purpose of the Queue in my program is to be able to make dynamic changes in a parallel process. The Queue is initiated in the main program and in continually being monitored in the parallel process.  A simplified version of how I am doing this in the parallel process is the following (with 'q' being the Queue):

```
while(1):

    if q.empty():
        None

    else:
        fr = q.get()
        # Additional code

    time.sleep(1)
```

The dynamic changes to 'q' do not happen very often so majority of the time q.empty() will be true, but the loop is there to be ready as soon as changes are made.  My question is, would running this code for multiple hours at a time cause the memory to eventually run low? With the 'while' loop being pretty short and running basically non stop, I was thinking this might be an problem.  If this could be the cause of the problem, does anybody have any suggestions on how to improve the code so the out of memory killer doesn't get called?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `if q.empty(): pass` is the idiomatic way to write that block. But it would be even better to just have `if not q.empty(): fr = q.get()` in the first place.

Comment: What implementation are you using? Is `.get()` removing the element from the queue or only inspecting it? In the latter case, the size of the queue is monotonically increasing.

Comment: do you have swap enabled?  what's the output of `free`?

Comment: Thank you for all the comments.  The way I am using .get() is to remove a list from the Queue.  So I am using .put() in the main program to send the list to the parallel process and .get() is what picks it up. I assumed previously that after .get() is entered, the Queue is cleared, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: I stopped running the program some time ago, but here is the current output of 'free':             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       8177396    1659060    6518336          0     255036     560160
-/+ buffers/cache:     843864    7333532
Swap:     10027004     869020    9157984

Comment: Did you try change /proc/<pid>/oom_score for your process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way you can run out of memory in the way you describe is if you're using more and more memory as time goes on. The loop here does *not* demonstrate this behavior, so it cannot be (solely) responsible for any memory errors. Running a tight, infinite loop can burn through a lot of needless processor cycles, but it can't cause a `MemoryError` by itself unless it's storing data to someplace else.

It's likely that elsewhere in your code, you're holding onto some variables that you don't intend to. This is called a memory leak, and you can use a [memory profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/110259/2069350) to look for where such a leak is coming from.

Some likely suspects are caching methods used to improve performance, or lists of variables that never leave scope. Perhaps your multiprocessing queue is holding on to references to earlier data objects, or items are never deleted from the queue once they're inserted? (This latter case is unlikely given the code you've shown if you're using the builtin `queue.Queue`, but anything is possible).

Comment: This is not an answer. Post it as a comment.

Comment: @Stefano How is this not an answer? `"My question is, would running this code for multiple hours at a time cause the memory to eventually run low?"` The answer is No, the given code cannot cause the program to run out of memory.

Comment: Your answer reads: _I cannot conclude that your code is causing this error by itself, please provide more details_. This is what I would put in a comment. And that piece of (pseudo)code can well be the cause, because you don't know the behaviour of `queue.get`.

Comment: @Stefano I'm assuming, for lack of other information, that he's using [`queue.Queue`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.get), which would not cause this behavior. The asker *didn't* ask us to find the memory leak, but rather *if it could be caused* by the tight loop in a parallel process. I've edited my answer to hopefully read less like a request for more information, though.

Comment: The question is not strictly limited to the loop, _" would running this code for multiple hours at a time cause the memory to eventually run low?"_. And, programmers should beware of assumptions. When in doubt, ask the OP.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert your program into a linux service and set its oom policy to continue.

You can check [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units) and [this](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#OOMPolicy=) links to see how to see/edit service parameters and see oom policy service parameter respectively.