# MemoryError Counting Eigenvalues for large matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvector for a 10304x10304 matrix. I'm using `numpy.linalg.eig`, and got a `MemoryError`.

Does this mean that I don't have enough RAM? Do I need to parallelize my code? If so, how would I do that?

complete code can be viewed [here](http://pastebin.com/LBPwPREA) 
Sorry if it's a mess, I'm so bad about this....

Comment: Please **show your code** so we know what we are trying to fix. How could anyone show you what is producing your `MemoryError` without seeing it?

Comment: I've added my code, sorry about that.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/which-python-memory-profiler-is-recommended). Also, consider refactoring your code to use lists and loops so you don't have to manually type out `a1` to `aN` assignments.

Comment: Storing your matrix alone in memory already takes around 800MB. Calculating `eig` will use at least that amount again. Depending on what else your system is doing, a laptop with 4G RAM may get a memory error, although it may be possible to run this if it is the only open program. 8GB should definitely do the trick.
The question that remains though is what you want to do with all those eigenvectors, values. If you are not using all of them, you should only calculate the ones you need, e.g. using `scipy.sparse.linalg.svds`

Comment: I'm gonna need all the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. The next step I'm planning to do is sort the eigenvectors based on their eigenvalues, and then transforming the eigenvectors that relevant to 2/3 lower eigenvalues of the whole matrix.

Comment: @Narqissa is your matrix sparse? in case yes, you should take a look at `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs` (non-symmetric matrices) or `eigsh` (symmetric matrices)