# Track variables in Python subprocesses

Tags: python, memory-management, subprocess, python-multithreading

I would like a way to trace how subprocesses in Python are using the memory. More precisely, I would like to get information about the variables used by each subprocess - whether they are copies of the main process variables, or they are shared among multiple subprocesses, etc.

Note that I am not interested in general techniques for debugging subprocesses in Python, I am aware of the numerous posts on that topic. I strictly want more information about the memory usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this answer can help you out. [Python Memory Profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/which-python-memory-profiler-is-recommended)

Example:

```
from guppy import hpy
h = hpy()
print h.heap()
```

Results

```
Partition of a set of 132527 objects. Total size = 8301532 bytes.
Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
0  35144  27  2140412  26   2140412  26 str
1  38397  29  1309020  16   3449432  42 tuple
2    530   0   739856   9   4189288  50 dict (no owner)
```

Also, there is a module, its easy to use and you can see the operations and the vars.

[memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler)

Looks something like this(extract from package's page):

```
Line #    Mem usage  Increment   Line Contents
==============================================
     3                           @profile
     4      5.97 MB    0.00 MB   def my_func():
     5     13.61 MB    7.64 MB       a = [1] * (10 ** 6)
     6    166.20 MB  152.59 MB       b = [2] * (2 * 10 ** 7)
     7     13.61 MB -152.59 MB       del b
     8     13.61 MB    0.00 MB       return a
```

Comment: This is a very good start, but I was wondering if I could see the actual names of the variables.

Comment: @JohnJaques i added something that may help you, check it.

Comment: Yes, this is very useful! I'll try it on multiple subprocesses to see how it behaves then.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a subprocess doesn't share *variables* with its parent. It might share *memory pages*, though.

On POSIX systems Python launches a subprocess by using `os.fork()` followed by `os.execvp()` or `os.execvpe()`. (On Windows it uses `CreateProcess()`, but I'll focus on POSIX.)

After the `fork`, the child process is a carbon copy of the parent. But unlike threads, they do not *share* memory (or variables) by design;  they are separate processes. A forked process does have a copy of its parent process's descriptors, pointing to the same files.
Depending on the OS's implementation of virtual memory management they might share memory pages using [copy on write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write#Copy-on-write_in_virtual_memory_management) ("COW").

However, shortly after that the child process calls `os.execvp` to *replace* itself with another program.
Now this new program might still share some memory pages using COW depending on the aforementioned virtual memory implementation. But it  cannot use variables from the process it replaces.

If you want the child process to be a Python function, you should look into [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html). There you *can* [share variables between processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).