# What is the best strategy to setup limits/requests in the kubernetes?

Tags: python, kubernetes

We have big problems with setting limits/requests in our web django servers/python processors/celery workers. Our current strategy is to look at the usage of the graphs in the last 7 days:

1) get raw average excluding peak

2) add 30% buffer

3) set limits 2 time requests

It works more or less, but then service's code is changed and limits which were set before are not valid anymore. What are the other strategies?

How would you set up limits/requests for those graphs:

1) Processors:

[image]

2) Celery-beat

[image]

3) Django (artifacts probably connected somehow to rollouts)

[image]

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "someone changes implementation and everything breaks" ?

Comment: `service's code is changed and limits which were set before are not valid anymore`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to start with the average CPU and memory value that the application takes and then enable **auto scaling**. Kunernetes has multiple kinds of autoscaling.

- Horizontal pod autoscaler
- Vertical pod autoscaler

[Horizontal pod autoscaling](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) is commonly used these days. HPA will automatically create new pods if the pods CPU or memory exceeds the percentage or volume of CPU or memory set as threshold.

Monitor the new releases before deployment and see why exactly the new release needs more memory. Troubleshoot and try to reduce the resource consumption limit. If that is not update the resource request with new CPU and memory value.

Comment: HPA is based on cpu requests. So firstly you must set up proper requests and limits, don't you?

Comment: You can start off with average memory and CPU values for requests and the max memory and CPU values as limits based on graph 1 in your question. And then say for HPA you can say if CPU crosses 60 percent of its limit or memory usage crosses 70 percentage of its limit, schedule another pod.

Comment: Why do average for requests and 60/70% for limits?