# How to return used memory after funtion call in python

Tags: python, memory-management

I am trying to write a python module which checks consistency of the mac addresses stored in the HW memory. The scale could go upto 80K mac addresses. But when I make multiple calls to get a list of mac addresses through a python method, the memory does not get freed up and eventually I am running out of memory.

An example of what I am doing is:

```
import resource
import copy


def get_list():
    list1 = None
    list1 = []
    for j in range(1,10):
        for i in range(0,1000000):
            list1.append('abcdefg')
        print(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss / 1000)
    return list1

for i in range(0,5):
    x=get_list()
```

On executing the script, I get:

```
45805
53805
61804
69804
77803
85803
93802
101801
109805
118075
126074
134074
142073
150073
158072
166072
174071
182075
190361
198361
206360
214360
222359
230359
238358
246358
254361
262365
270364
278364
286363
294363
302362
310362
318361
326365
334368
342368
350367
358367
366366
374366
382365
390365
398368
```

i.e. the memory usage reported keeps going up.
Is it that I am looking at the memory usage in a wrong way?
And if not, is there a way to not have the memory usage go up between function calls in a loop. (In my case with mac addresses, I do not call the same list of mac addresses again. I get the list from a different section of the HW memory. i.e. all the calls to get mac addresses are valid, but after each call the data obtained is useless and can be discarded.

Comment: What OS and python version?

Comment: python 2.7 seen is both os x mavericks and linux

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/which-python-memory-profiler-is-recommended for memory profilers, which will point you to where your objects are being referenced so that the garbage collector is unable to reclaim them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is a *managed* language.  Memory is, generally speaking, the concern of the implementation rather than the average developer.  The system is designed to reclaim memory that you are no longer using automatically.

If you are using CPython, an object will be destroyed when its reference count reaches zero, or when the cyclic garbage collector finds and collects it.  If you want to reclaim the memory belonging to an object, you need to ensure that no references to it remain, or at least that it is not reachable from any stack frame's variables.  That is to say, it should not be possible to refer to the data you want reclaimed, either directly or through some expression such as `foo.bar[42]`, from any currently executing function.

If you are using another implementation, such as PyPy, the rules may vary.  In particular, reference counting is not required by the Python language standard, so objects may not go away until the next garbage collection run (and then you may have to wait for the right [generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Generational) to be collected).

For older versions of Python (prior to [Python 3.4](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0442/)), you also need to worry about reference cycles which involve finalizers (`__del__()` methods).  The old garbage collector cannot collect such cycles, so they will (basically) [get leaked](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.garbage).  Most built-in types do not have finalizers, are not capable of participating in reference cycles, or both, but this is a legitimate concern if you are creating your own classes.

---

For your use case, you should empty or replace the list when you no longer need its contents (with e.g. `list1 = []` or `del list1[:]`), or return from the function which created it (assuming it's a local variable, rather than a global variable or some other such thing).  If you find that you are still running out of memory after that, you should either switch to a lower-overhead language like C or invest in more memory.  For more complicated cases, you can use the [`gc` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html) to test and evaluate how the garbage collector is interacting with your program.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : it might not Lways free the memory as it may still be in use. 
See if it works

```
gc.collect()
```