# How to find the source of a MemoryError in Python?

Tags: python, hyperopt

I'm running a hyperparameter optimization using Hyperopt for a Neural Network. While doing so, after some iterations, I get a MemoryError exception

So far, I tried clearing all variables after they had been used (assigning None or empty lists to them, is there a better way for this?) and printing all locals(), dirs() and globals() with their sizes, but those counts never increase and the sizes are quite small.

The structure looks like this:

```py
def create_model(params):
    ## load data from temp files
    ## pre-process data accordingly
    ## Train NN with crossvalidation clearing Keras' session every time
    ## save stats and clean all variables (assigning None or empty lists to them)

def Optimize():
    for model in models: #I have multiple models
        ## load data
        ## save data to temp files
        trials = Trials()
        best_run = fmin(create_model,
                        space,
                        algo=tpe.suggest,
                        max_evals=100,
                        trials=trials)
```

After X number of iterations (sometimes it completes the firsts 100 and shifts to the second model) it throws a memory error.
My guess is that some variables remain in memory and I'm not clearing them, but I wasn't able to detect them.

**EDIT:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 32, in <module>
    optimal = Optimize(training_sets)
  File "/home/User1/Optimizer/optimization2.py", line 394, in Optimize
    trials=trials)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 307, in fmin
    return_argmin=return_argmin,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/hyperopt/base.py", line 635, in fmin
    return_argmin=return_argmin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 320, in fmin
    rval.exhaust()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 199, in exhaust
    self.run(self.max_evals - n_done, block_until_done=self.async)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 173, in run
    self.serial_evaluate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 92, in serial_evaluate
    result = self.domain.evaluate(spec, ctrl)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/hyperopt/base.py", line 840, in evaluate
    rval = self.fn(pyll_rval)
  File "/home/User1/Optimizer/optimization2.py", line 184, in create_model
    x_train, x_test = x[train_indices], x[val_indices]
MemoryError
```

Comment: Could you add this error with the full stack trace in your question?

Comment: Let me re-run it and I'll extract that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/which-python-memory-profiler-is-recommended

Comment: @AlexJadczak that was useful. I used `memory_profiler` and 90% of the memory is generated in the line that calls to `fmin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a couple of days to figure this out so I'll answer my own question to save whoever encounters this issue some time.

Usually, when using Hyperopt for Keras, the suggested `return` of the `create_model` function is something like this:

```
return {'loss': -acc, 'status': STATUS_OK, 'model': model}
```

But in large models, with many evaluations, you don't want to return and save in memory every model, all you need is the set of Hyperparameters that gave the lowest `loss`

By simply removing the model from the returned dict, the issue of memory increasing with each evaluation is resolved.

```
return {'loss': -acc, 'status': STATUS_OK}
```