# which part of the code is using memory? and how do I use 'del' to reset the memory?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, image-processing, keras, ram

for one epoch for this image process using more than 80 ram memory
I know the 'del' command to delete the memory usage

> del dataframe

I want to use 'del' command to free the memory after one epoch
but not sure which one is actually using the memory for this code 
here is the code

```
for train_index, valid_index in zip(train_indexes,valid_indexes):

    print("cleanup memory")
    traindf = df_train.iloc[train_index, :].reset_index()
    validdf = df_train.iloc[valid_index, :].reset_index()

        if(j >= 1 and j <= 1):

        train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
            dataframe=traindf,
            directory=TRAIN_CROPPED_PATH,
            x_col='img_file',
            y_col='class',
            target_size= (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
            color_mode='rgb',
            class_mode='categorical',
            batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
            seed=SEED,
            shuffle=True
            )

        valid_generator = valid_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
            dataframe=validdf,
            directory=TRAIN_CROPPED_PATH,
            x_col='img_file',
            y_col='class',
            color_mode='rgb',
            class_mode='categorical',
            batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
            seed=SEED,
            shuffle=True
            )

        model_name = model_path + str(j) + '_'+ modelName+"_Aug"+'.hdf5'
        model_names.append(model_name)

        print("TRAIN_CROPPED_PATH:",TRAIN_CROPPED_PATH)
        print("model_name:",model_name)

        model = get_model()

        try:
            model.load_weights(model_name)
        except:
            pass

        print("model_path:",model_path)

        patient = 2
        callbacks = [
        EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=patient, mode='min', verbose=1),
        ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor = 'val_loss', factor = 0.5, patience = patient / 2, min_lr=0.00001, verbose=1, mode='min'),
        ModelCheckpoint(filepath=model_name, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min'),
        ]

        history = model.fit_generator(
            train_generator,
            steps_per_epoch=len(traindf.index) / BATCH_SIZE,
            epochs=epochs,
            validation_data=valid_generator,
            validation_steps=len(validdf.index) / BATCH_SIZE,
            verbose=1,
            shuffle=False,
           callbacks = callbacks
            )

    j+=1
```

Comment: `del` is not for "resetting memory", it's for removing names from namespaces.

Comment: when I load the dataframe and del dataframe it remove the usage of that dataframe memory

Comment: something = read.csv("a") and I used  del something

Comment: Yes, because when you *removed the name from the namespace, the reference count of the object reached 0 and it was reclaimed*. This is *incidental* to what `del` does. The best way to keep your memory usage under control is to use function/classes and don't just plop everything into the global scope, which will keep references around indefinitely. Rather, try to keep things as local as possible, and the the reference counting mechanism will do the work for you.

Comment: @jake Try a python memory profiler like lprof. There is a good discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/110259/3429090