# Python remote process diagnostic tool

Tags: python, memory-leaks, remote-debugging, jvisualvm, diagnostic-tools

I have a python distributed app running in IBM symphony compute cloud. for one of the batch runs in the app, I see massive swaps due to ram of few hosts nearly getting full.

So I am looking for any tool and setting for python, which can enable me to diagnose each of these processes and see if there is any possible memory leak. I have used JVisual VM and Mission Control in Java before, but could not find any similar tool for python.

Also, any advice on forcing/ensuring garbage collection in python would be helpful.

Comment: i can see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/which-python-memory-profiler-is-recommended but not sure if it is totally effective