# How is one supposed to use the Pool initializer argument

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pybind11

I've got a function `foo` which takes a small object and a large one `big_object`. The large one is a constant. I'm using multiprocessing to process a list of the small objects. I want to avoid having to pickle/unpickle `big_object` each time `foo` is called.

It seems like the `initialiser` argument of `multiprocessing.Pool` would be useful for me. But I can't figure it out (memory explodes). My approach at the moment looks like:

```
big_object = None

def foo(small_object):
   global big_object
   # ... do stuff with big_object
   return result

def init(big_object_arg):
   global big_object
   big_object = big_object_arg

def main():
   [...]
   with mp.Pool(4, initializer=init, initargs=(big_object,)) as pool:
       lst_results = pool.map(foo, lst_small_objects)
```

This runs, but memory usage explodes for some reason. Why could this be happening?

`big_object` is a custom C++ object defined via pybind11 for which I have defined pickling functions. These are very slow though.

Comment: Have you looked at _what_ causes the memory to explode? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/which-python-memory-profiler-is-recommended for ways to do that

Answer (score 0):

So, the memory blowing up was fine and actually expected. At the same time it was not actually running because I was using a custom C++ object and there was a bug in the pickling code.

In other words, the code I posted is fine. That works!