# Fastapi: Does not free memory

Tags: memory, fastapi

I have functionality which is using multi-threading for downloading files, and Fastapi not releasing memory after tasks are done. Api using 1 worker. If I repeat tasks, memory is appending all the time, not releasing previously. Does anyone know how to find what is problem?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, verifiable example of the problem. For tools, start with the larger threads on SO for debuggers, profilers and memory profilers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/which-python-memory-profiler-is-recommended